# How to sort the legend in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, char, jfreechart, legend

Is there a way to sort the items in a JFreeChart legend by their backing object?

I've noticed that the TimeSeries/Series sets the title via a Comparable object.

Is there a way or a setting that forces the legend to be sorted by the comparable objects that the items are representing? Currently the legend is sorted by FIFO order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `add()` method of [`LegendItemCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/LegendItemCollection.html) to add the items in the desired order. Most `Plot`s have a `setFixedLegendItems()` method to override the default.

Comment: I use default colors in my stack bar chart (not setting them). Can I somehow order the labels automatically, to preserve their correlation with data colors?

Comment: A suitable [`DrawingSupplier`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjfreechart%5D+DrawingSupplier) should work; see [ask] if you get stuck.