# Adding legend to jFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have come up with my final hysteresis plot, which looks like this:

[image]

My earlier post:
[Plotting a hysteresis loop with jFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952712/plotting-a-hysteresis-loop-with-jfreechart)

I have used 4 XYSeries for my first hysteresis loop and another four for the second hysteresis loop.

If i turn on the legend

```
 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
"Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
"Pounds(lb)", // domain axis label
"Movement(inch)", // range axis label
dataset, // data
PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
true, // include legend
true, // tooltips
false // urls
);
```

it appears like this :

[image]

I just want to show that blue is my first hysteresis loop and red is my second hysteresis loop, which I have added as subtitle in the first pic as workaround. Can someone guide how I can add manual legends which indicate blue as first loop and red as second.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()` creates an `XYPlot`, you could try [`setFixedLegendItems()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setFixedLegendItems%28org.jfree.chart.LegendItemCollection%29), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5431509/230513) and [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/search.php?keywords=setFixedLegendItems).

A more ambitious scheme is to suppress the native legend and render the legend items in a separate component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513).