# How to change shape of elements in the legend - jFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart, shapes, legend

How I can change the shape of elements of legend for jFreeChart without changing the graphs of diagrams ?

[image]

I have ready time series diagram. I need to update the existed data markers in legend to the simple line with defined colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by *not* adding a `LegendTitle` to your chart. This is usually a controlled by a parameter to your `ChartFactory` or your `JFreeChart` constructor. Both `CategoryPlot` and `XYPlot` have a `setFixedLegendItems()` method, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15001231/230513), that you can use to add a collection of arbitrary legend items.

Comment: Problem is that I have hardcoded legend in jrxml-file, and I can't to redefine something in legend, excluding the markers.

Comment: I don't understand. Please update your question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: I don't understand where you had trouble using the approach I suggested. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comment - it led me to the right decision!
Can you hint me something another problem ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863515/barchart-text-trancation-problems