# BarChart text truncation problems

Tags: jfreechart, bar-chart

I have two problem, which can be illustrated by these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

So, how to avoid text's truncation in these case ? Of course, the width is enough.Moreover, truncation differs for differen strings.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or [preferred size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) problem. You can override `getPreferredSize()` in `ChartPanel` to get a nice initial display, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513), and specify a layout like `BorderLayout.CENTER` or `GridLayout` to let the panel adopt the size of the enclosing `Container`. Failing this, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem you encounter.